# Make a /dev/hwrng kernel module which use cursor position for generate entropy

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, entropy

I am new to kernel development, so for increase my skills i want to made a simple kernel module which set up the device /dev/hwrng and generate some entropy with cursor position.

For the moment i have found the way to launch /dev/hwrng and generated only zero as entropy => http://main.lv/writeup/kernel_dev_hwrng.md

For get the cursor position I know differents ways:

- from library X11/Xlib.h -> i can get absolute position of my cursor
- from `/dev/input/mice` and `/dev/input/mouse0` -> i can get the relative position
- form `/dev/input/event<X>` where X is a number which is find with the command `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

So i know how to get the cursor position in user land but i have no idea of how to get it from the kernel land. I have read something about IOCTL but it seems weird to make a connection between userland and kernel land just for that.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I doubt cursor absolute position is even known in the kernel. The X server knows, because it's drawing it (I think), but that's taking the relative mouse movement from the device driver. But the X server is a user land process, can't see a reason why that'd go back into the kernel. And if you consider that an X server can be remote, over a network, then it's entirely separate to the underlying kernel.

Comment: I agree with that, there is no reason the kernel knows the cursor position. So I am trying to use as input for my entropy module the cursor position, I am thinking using one of the /dev/input device, but I have no idea if it's possible just with the kernel space, and if it is, I don't know how to doing it.

Comment: Sure, but in your kernel module the randomness coming from input devices is only derived from what a user is doing if they're locally logged in. If they're remotely logged in then there's zero input going on locally, which would be a bad thing considering what you have in mind; it would be constant zero input.

Comment: You right, what i want to do is not secure but it is just a Proof Of Concept, the purpose is just to set up a device (hwrng) which be sourced in entropy just with the cursor position. So, as a POC it will run in Controlled environment (with a logged user).

Comment: In that case I think that the best suggestion is @Ed Jaras's (below), your second bullet point. You can read the mouse events/data easily enough in the kernel, but you can't turn them into an absolute mouse poisiton because that's a concept that exists only in the X server, which isn't going to tell any process where it thinks the mouse is unless it's one of its clients (that excludes the kernel). You could just take the mouse event data and treat it as a stream of randomness.

Comment: I will try in that way, and give a return as soon as I will find a way to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise looking at this first: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/how-do-mouse-events-work-in-linux 
The short version would be that you can access the same device files from kernel space.